# What do output comments "required from" messages indicate when generated by 'make'?

Tags: c++, makefile

I just tried to use make to build code from [gr-sidekiq](https://github.com/epiqsolutions/gr-sidekiq). When doing so, I got several output lines starting with the phrase 'required from', whose meaning is unclear to me.

```
(radioconda) me@memfish1:~/Projects/gr-sidekiq/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target gnuradio-sidekiq
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-sidekiq.dir/sidekiq_tx_impl.cc.o
In file included from /home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/spdlog/fmt/fmt.h:31,
                 from /home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/spdlog/common.h:45,
                 from /home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/gnuradio/logger.h:36,
                 from /home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/gnuradio/custom_lock.h:15,
                 from /home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/gnuradio/buffer.h:15,
                 from /home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/gnuradio/buffer_double_mapped.h:15,
                 from /home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/gnuradio/io_signature.h:23,
                 from /home/me/Projects/gr-sidekiq/lib/sidekiq_tx_impl.cc:7:
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/fmt/core.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr fmt::v9::detail::value<Context> fmt::v9::detail::make_value(T&&) [with Context = fmt::v9::basic_format_context<fmt::v9::appender, char>; T = const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&]’:
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/fmt/core.h:1777:29:   required from ‘constexpr fmt::v9::detail::value<Context> fmt::v9::detail::make_arg(T&&) [with bool IS_PACKED = true; Context = fmt::v9::basic_format_context<fmt::v9::appender, char>; fmt::v9::detail::type <anonymous> = fmt::v9::detail::type::custom_type; T = const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&; typename std::enable_if<IS_PACKED, int>::type <anonymous> = 0]’
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/fmt/core.h:1901:77:   required from ‘constexpr fmt::v9::format_arg_store<Context, Args>::format_arg_store(T&& ...) [with T = {const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&}; Context = fmt::v9::basic_format_context<fmt::v9::appender, char>; Args = {std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>}]’
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/spdlog/logger.h:381:5:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::log_(spdlog::source_loc, spdlog::level::level_enum, spdlog::string_view_t, Args&& ...) [with Args = {const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&}; spdlog::string_view_t = fmt::v9::basic_string_view<char>]’
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/spdlog/logger.h:90:9:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::log(spdlog::source_loc, spdlog::level::level_enum, fmt::v9::format_string<T ...>, Args&& ...) [with Args = {const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&}; fmt::v9::format_string<T ...> = fmt::v9::basic_format_string<char, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&>]’
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/spdlog/logger.h:96:9:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::log(spdlog::level::level_enum, fmt::v9::format_string<T ...>, Args&& ...) [with Args = {const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&}; fmt::v9::format_string<T ...> = fmt::v9::basic_format_string<char, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&>]’
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/spdlog/logger.h:152:9:   required from ‘void spdlog::logger::debug(fmt::v9::format_string<T ...>, Args&& ...) [with Args = {const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&}; fmt::v9::format_string<T ...> = fmt::v9::basic_format_string<char, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&, const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&>]’
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/gnuradio/logger.h:166:9:   required from ‘void gr::logger::debug(const string_view_t&, const Args& ...) [with Args = {std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>}; spdlog::string_view_t = fmt::v9::basic_string_view<char>]’
/home/me/Projects/gr-sidekiq/lib/sidekiq_tx_impl.cc:348:26:   required from here
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/spdlog/logger.h:374:75:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘fmt::v9::make_format_args<>(std::forward<const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&>(args#0), std::forward<const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&>(args#1), std::forward<const std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>&>(args#2))’
/home/me/anaconda3/envs/radioconda/include/fmt/core.h:1757:7: error: static assertion failed: Cannot format an argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#udt
 1757 |       formattable,
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-sidekiq.dir/build.make:63: lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-sidekiq.dir/sidekiq_tx_impl.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:269: lib/CMakeFiles/gnuradio-sidekiq.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Are the 'required from' lines informing me of some error each time they occur? Are they some sort of a trace explaining why the final error occurred? Or are they merely informative, and if so what are they telling me?

Comment: I think the error is related to formatting an argument using the `fmt` library, and check your code in `sidekiq_tx_impl.cc` at line `348` to understand the problem.

Comment: In the old days you'd just get an error message in the deep-dark of some library and have to piece together how your code made this far-away code written by someone else so angry. This trace shows you how the compiler got from your code to this other code so you can see where you need to start investigating.

Comment: @BugHunter - So, do I have two errors here? One caused by line `348` in `sidekiq_tx_impl.cc`  and another an line `1757` of `/include/fmt/core.h`?

Comment: One way or another, it looks like the format argument provided is invalid, line 348 in sidekiq_tx_impl.cc resulted in a single error that manifests on line 1757 in /include/fmt/core.h.